# QuickFIX/J - How to handle library exceptions (as "QFJException: Unknown or unsupported ApplVerID") on application?

Tags: quickfixj

I have a question about how to manage the `QFJException` error on the server side when an invalid `DefaultApplVerID` is used (as 55) in the Login request to the server.

Currently, the callbacks in the Application interface **do not receive this error and the socket connection remains open**.

What I want to do is to manage this error as a server and send RejectLogon to the user (or directly disconnect its connection).

---

Quickfixj Version = 2.3.1

Server config:

```
[default]
ConnectionType=acceptor
...
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2
...
UseDataDictionary=Y
RejectGarbledMessage=Y
```

---

Test data:

- Logon request with incorrect DefaultApplVerID (1137=55):

```
21:57:32.746 [NioProcessor-12] INFO quickfixj.msg.incoming - FIXT.1.1:EXCHANGE->XYZ/SUB1: 8=FIXT.1.19=12635=A49=XYZ56=EXCHANGE34=152=20231012-18:57:3250=SUB1553=USER_NAME554=123456108=600098=01137=55141=Y10=035
```

- Error stacktrace:

```
21:59:34.328 [NioProcessor-12] ERROR quickfix.mina.acceptor.AcceptorIoHandler - org.quickfixj.QFJException: Unknown or unsupported ApplVerID: 55
org.quickfixj.QFJException: Unknown or unsupported ApplVerID: 55
    at quickfix.MessageUtils.toBeginString(MessageUtils.java:294)
    at quickfix.DefaultDataDictionaryProvider.lambda$new$1(DefaultDataDictionaryProvider.java:50)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
    at org.quickfixj.SimpleCache.computeIfAbsent(SimpleCache.java:41)
    at quickfix.DefaultDataDictionaryProvider.getApplicationDataDictionary(DefaultDataDictionaryProvider.java:67)
    at quickfix.MessageUtils.parse(MessageUtils.java:147)
    at quickfix.mina.AbstractIoHandler.messageReceived(AbstractIoHandler.java:129)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1015)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:650)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1300(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1128)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter$ProtocolDecoderOutputImpl.flush(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:418)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter.messageReceived(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:257)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:650)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1300(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1128)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.messageReceived(IoFilterAdapter.java:122)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:650)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:643)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:539)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$1200(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:68)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1224)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1213)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:683)
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like a bug to me. I would have expected to go this way: https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/blob/37add8a2b7d5419c70b63628ab36db24b61eed62/quickfixj-core/src/main/java/quickfix/mina/AbstractIoHandler.java#L140 but the QFJException (instead of InvalidMessage) throws it off track. I could imagine that this also happens on messages with an unknown ApplVerID after the session has already been established.

Comment: We also encountered the following situation: After the user logged in with an incorrect  DefaultApplVerID, when the user corrected the DefaultApplVerID and tried to log in again, Quickfix was again giving an error with the previous incorrect DefaultApplVerID 
 (org.quickfixj.QFJException: Unknown or unsupported ApplVerID: xx).

Comment: Maybe you should open a separate bug for that.

Comment: Thanks @ChristophJohn. I'll open the relevant bugs.

Comment: https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/issues/681